# Why is @rendermode InteractiveAuto not working in .NET 8.0 Blazor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I created a Blazor Web App project with the following settings.

[image]

When I launch, despite the `Counter.razor` component containing `@rendermode InteractiveAuto`, the Counter page does not download WASM and switch over from server. In the browser's Network tab the websocket remains active.

Additionally, I put the following code into the `NavMenu.razor` component. The text never switches over to WASM.

```
<h1 class="text-muted">Render @(OperatingSystem.IsBrowser() ? "Wasm" : "Server")</h1>
```

According to [this video](https://youtu.be/YwZdtLEtROA?t=2364), it should download WASM and switch over.

To solve it, I tried using different browsers and making my own component with the InteractiveAuto render mode.

What is the issue here?

`Counter.razor` file in the client project:

```
@page "/counter"
@rendermode InteractiveAuto

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

`Program.cs` file in the client project:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;

var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

`Program.cs` file in the server project:

```
using TestBlazorProj.Client.Pages;
using TestBlazorProj.Components;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyComponents();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAntiforgery();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode()
    .AddAdditionalAssemblies(typeof(Counter).Assembly);

app.Run();
```

`App.razor` file in the server project.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="TestBlazorProj.styles.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <HeadOutlet />
</head>

<body>
    <Routes />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include your component code/page that contains Counter.razor and your program.cs page. Note that the switch to WASM also only happens on subsequent page loads, not the first one.

Comment: @TylerH Yes, so if navigate through pages or reload pages it still does not switch over.

Comment: What's in your App.razor route definition.  If you have set something like  <Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" /> at the global level, I suspect that will override the component definition.

Comment: @gwruck I updated the question with `App.razor` file's contents. I do not have that attribute set. To be clear, except for the `<h1>` tag, I did not modify any code after creating the project template.

Comment: After posting my comment, I realised it probably wouldn't be set there because the wasm components in the client project would break if it was set to globally render InteractiveServer.

Comment: I made a new project and launched it. Something I noticed is that on the first launch, it does behave as the videos shows - the web socket is active and downloads WASM,I browse around and the socket closes, which I assume means it switched to WASM. @TylerH, is this what you meant? However, the sockets remain open on subsequent page loads even if the app is fully relaunched.

Comment: Relating to my comment above, the `OperatingSystem.IsBrowser()` never displays "Wasm" even if initially WASM is downloaded and socket is closed.

Comment: Try putting the <h1 class="text-muted">Render @(OperatingSystem.IsBrowser() ? "Wasm" : "Server")</h1> statement in the Counter component.  I think you'll find it will change when it switches from server to WASM.  As to WHY the location of this tag matters, I'm still trying to figure that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beacuse your NavMenu component is still in Static(by default), applying a render mode per page with `@rendermode InteractiveAuto` would only affect the current component; it won't affect other child components in the parent component.

If you add this line

```
<h1 class="text-muted">Render @(OperatingSystem.IsBrowser() ? "Wasm" : "Server")</h1>
```

in your Counter component, you would see:

[image]

You could check this document for more details: [Child components with different render modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0#child-components-with-different-render-modes)

Comment: Thank you. In other words, the nav saying "Render Server" does not mean there's an active socket rendering the nav. It just means that the html was returned from the server, just like in a regular MVC app would. It does not switch to WASM because that component does not have or need the `@rendermode InteractiveAuto` since it's not interactive. It's just static HTML. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes,you're correct